# Recognizing the coded type of mp4

Tags: java, video, media, xuggler, mpeg-4

I am working on a Java based media management platform where users can upload media files and preview them. Preview generation is done using xuggler and based on the following logic:

```
    if (can be played in a browser) {
        directly upload
    } else {
        transcode into supported formats(mp4,avi)
    }
```

Even though mp4 is supported by browsers, some of the mp4 videos cannot be played directly.

1. Can this be due to unsupported codecs?
2. If so, how can I determine not only the media type, but the codec type of a media file as well?